# Qt Designer не запускается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

Установил *PyQt5*. 
После скачал через сайт *Qt Designer*. 
Установка прошла успешно, но когда я пытаюсь запустить его, он не реагирует.
Просто идет анимация загрузки и все. Я запускал и через пользователя и через администратора.

Не знаю в чем проблема, но это может быть связано с тем, что у меня **32 бит пк**?

Я также устанавливал через `cmd pip install pyqt5-tools` и установка прошла, но даже так не видит.